# Does Unity offer anything similar to Ninject custom providers?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, ninject

does Unity (any version) provide anything similar to Ninject custom providers as described [here](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Providers%20and%20the%20Activation%20Context)?  I need to access contextual information at the point of type resolution.  Specifically, I need access to the type which invoked the resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it directly, but I think you could achieve something similar by doing the following:

```
    public interface IMyType
{
    //whatever you need
}

public interface IMyTypeProvider
{
    IMyType Create(object context);
}

public class MyTypeProvider : IMyTypeProvider
{
    public IMyType Create(object context)
    {
        //construct required instance based on context
    }
}

public class ClassWhichNeedsMyType
{
    public ClassWhichNeedsMyType(IMyTypeProvider provider)
    {
        this.myType = provider.Create(this);
    }

    private IMyType myType;
}
```

then register the provider with the container, and use that to construct your dependency:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyTypeProvider, MyTypeProvider>();
```

Comment: Thank you, ended up using a similar approach